# A particular selection of rows in upper triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, random-matrices, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory

Let $A$ be a  strictly  upper triangular $n\times n$ matrix whose entries are either 0 or 1 (diagonal entries are all 0) with the nullity  $m<n$.
Let us denote $R_j$ and $C_j$ with the rows and columns of $A$ respectively where $j=1,\cdots,n$.

Q. Can we find the following lists  in $\{1,\cdots,n\}$
$$r(1), r(2), \cdots, r(m)$$
$$c(1), c(2), \cdots, c(m)$$
such that the following two items simultaneously hold?

1. $\{R_j: j\notin \{r(k)\}_{k=1}^m\}$ and $\{C_j: j\notin \{c(k)\}_{k=1}^m\}$ are both linearly independent.
2. Let $A_0$ be the $m\times m$ submatrix of $A$ by the intersection of   the rows  $R_{r(1)}, R_{r(2)}, \cdots, R_{r(m)}$ and columns    $C_{c(1)}, C_{c(2)}, \cdots, C_{c(m)}$. The diagonal entries of $A_0$ are all 0.

Comment: The value of $m$ can not be fixed as the last row of $A$ is all zeros. In 1. why not define the sets as $\{R_j : j\in \{r(k)\}_{k=1}^s\}$ ($s=n-m$) etc. For 2. if $A_0$ is a principal submatrix  (equal lists) its diagonal is a subset of that of $A$ so it is also zero...